# dynamic pagination for fetched value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to make the select box with values 10,30,50 and need to pass this value to controller pagination method in laravel 5.3.Is it possible in laravel how to pass the val.

```
Router:
   Route::get('get-details','ApprovalController@getDetails');

  controller:
   public function getDetails(Request $request,$n)
   {
     users=$users->paginate($n) ;  /$n=10 or 30 or 50  /
   } 

 html
  <select class="row_count"  name="pagination">
  <option>10</option>
  <option>30</option>
  <option>50</option>
  </select>
  $(document).on('change', '.row_count', function() {
  var count $('.row_count').val();
   $.ajax({
    url: 'get-details',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      'count': count
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      location.reload();
    },
  });
```

Comment: Please understand actual structure of laravel paginate. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

Comment: You can use `$results->perPage()` to update the records in page `10,30,50` but their is no such functionality to get records in different sequence.